# Mongo query for finding out field matching particular array key value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to find out elements where type="Normal" and desc==atr.value (atr.value for a particular key atr.key="UDSP"). I am using mongo 3.0.4 so can't use $expr. Below is the dataset :

JSON

```
   "_id":ObjectId("12345"),
   "desc":"Foo Bar",
   "type":"Normal",
   "atr":[
      {
         "key":"DSP",
         "value":"Goo Bar"
      },
      {
         "key":"UDSP",
         "value":"Foo Bar"
      }
   ],
   "prod":"yes"
}
{
   "_id":ObjectId("12347"),
   "desc":"Boo Bar",
   "type":"Normal",
   "atr":[
      {
         "key":"DSP",
         "value":"Goo Bar"
      },
      {
         "key":"UDSP",
         "value":"Foo Bar"
      }
   ],
   "prod":"yes"
}
```

It should give result as Ist object only as type="Normal" and atr.value="Foo Bar"(for atr.key="UDSP") and desc="Foo Bar"

Comment: I have tried this query not not working : `db.test.aggregate([
   {
      $unwind:"$atr"
   },
   {
      "$match":{
         "atr.key":"UDSP"
      }
   },
   {
      "$redact":{
         "$cond":{
            if:{
               "$eq":[
                  "atr.value",
                  "desc"
               ]
            },
            then:"$$KEEP",
            else:"$$PRUNE"
         }
      }
   }
])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query. First add a field for matched document based on condition and filter based on added field

```
db.test.aggregate([ 
    { $match: { type: "Normal", "atr.key":"UDSP" }},
    { $addFields:{ 
        isDocMatched: { 
          $anyElementTrue: { 
              $map:{
                  input: "$atr",
                  as: "grade",
                  in: { $eq: [ "$$grade.value", "$desc" ] }
              }
          }
       }
    }},
    { $match: { isDocMatched: true } }  
])
```

Comment: seems '$addFields' not supported in Mongo 3.0.4. Giving error 16436 - "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$addFields"'

Comment: Then use $project stage instead of $addFileds. Take care of include ROOT element too. Thanks.